# Beating scipy's sparse matrix multiplication

Tags: multiplication, sparse-matrices

I develop an application that makes extensive use of sparse matrix operations.

Recently, I found out that scipy takes a lot of time checking matrix sizes and what not, up to the point that the checks take more time than the actual operations. See the posted issue with some metrics [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/10812).

So I decided to start the dubious enterprise of making my own sparse matrix library [CSparse3](https://github.com/SanPen/CSparse3).

At the moment, using numba, my library is only a 30% slower than scipy in a (+, *, /, -) test. And it is because of the matrix multiplication. Currently, I am using the algorithm from [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0898716136).

I am struggling to find other competitive CSC sparse matrix algorithms that are explained for humans. So I'd be grateful to know about better ones if available (with emphasis in the explained for humans part).

Comment: Are you looking for algorithms for multiplying sparse matrices?

Comment: You link to a specific algorithm, but the link goes to an entire book, which is moreover not available online. Those of us not in possession of the book therefore cannot really understand the question, let alone answer it. Can you include the algorithm you're currently using?

Comment: Yes, I look for CSC sparse matrix multiplication algorithms. Unfortunately I do not have any other source for the algorithm than the book. However you may have a look at the code which is LGPL3. Particularly here: https://github.com/SanPen/CSparse3/blob/master/src/CSparse/multiply.py